# ADXL345 accelerometer doesn't work

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, gyroscope

I just got the ADXL345 accelerometer module. I tried everything I could find online but I can't get it work. Here's how I connect the pins to the arduino uno:

```
ADXL345    ->     ARDUINO
  VCC               3.3V
  CS                3.3V
  GND               GND
  SDA               SDA
  SCL               SCL
```

I also use 2 10kOhm resistors from SDA, SCL to 3.3V on arduino. I tried both Adafruit and SparkFun ADXL345 libraries but it doesn't work. Using Adafruit library it says that no adxl345 is connected. I tried to connect SDO to 3.3V pin and then it stopped saying no adxl345 is connected but still didn't work (no x,y,z values displayed). Then I tried SparkFun library without connecting SDO to 3.3V (because it failed) and all I got was 0, 0, 0. I literally tried everything I could find from videos, tutorials, etc. I don't know why it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I already ordered the MPU6050. Is it any better?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my experience goes you donot have to connect it to pulldown resistors. If using a 5v Arduino, simply connect it like:

VCC --> 5V  (Arduino)
GND --> GND (Arduino)
SDA --> A4 or SDA (Arduino Uno has dedicated I2C pins beside AREF pin)
SCL --> A5 or SCL

This is all you need. As although the ADXL345 is a 3.3v MEMS, its module comes with a 5v to 3.3v converter and also goes through its startup procedure ([Refer datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf)) for you.
As for the library you can use this one [here](https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-ADXL345)
Also you can refer this article for detailed usage [here](http://www.jarzebski.pl/arduino/czujniki-i-sensory/3-osiowy-akcelerometr-adxl345.html)
And I hope next time you put in some more research and then buy a new part.

Answer (score 0):

SDO should be tied to ground, not 3.3V. That puts it into I2C mode.

VDDIO, VS and CS all need to be on 3.3V.

To communicate with an Arduino at 5V you really need a 5V -> 3.3V I2C level shifter. I use the PCA9306DCUR.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50079/discussion-on-answer-by-majenko-adxl345-accelerometer-doesnt-work).

Comment: The ADXL345 module already has a level shifter.

Comment: @SupragyMishra How do you know? No specific module has been specified, only the chip that is on the module.

Comment: Most modules ship with a shifter and note that he refered VCC not Vdd (digital supply) and Vs (supply voltage)

Comment: @SupragyMishra A module having a voltage regulator (common) does not mean that the module has a logic level translator (rare). The Adafruit one is the only one I have found that has a level translator. All the others don't. VCC and VDD don't imply any voltage. One is the collector voltage (from the old TTL days) and the other is the drain voltage (CMOS terminology). Nothing there implies any voltage.

Comment: @Majenko Okay. I did my research and yeah the pins DONOT imply any voltage... And the ADXLs I have with me do have a regulator not a SHIFTER. But the 5v logic works okay with the I2c Lines. So i just assumed it would work with Dimchtz's sensor

Comment: @SupragyMishra In general I2C is fairly tolerant of differing voltages as it's an open-drain bus system. Pull the bus up to the higher voltage and hope the current through the pullup resistors isn't too high for the ESD diodes in the lower-voltage device. The majority of times that's perfectly fine.